# Proof of Hilbert-Serre [Atiyah-Macdonald thm 11.1]

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, dimension-theory-algebra

I was very confused, for proving the Hilbert-Serre thm.
The following is our assumptions.

1. $A=\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n$ is graded Noetherian ring, so $A$ is finitely generated $A_0$-algebra, generated by homogeneous elements $x_1,\cdots,x_s$ each of which has degree $k_i$.
2. $M=\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}M_n$ is finitely generated graded $A$-module, and each $M_n$ turns out to be a finitely generated $A_0$-module.
3. $\lambda$ is additive function on the class of finitely generated $A_0$-module.
4. $P$ is generating function w.r.t $\lambda(M_n)$, i.e., $P(M,t)=\Sigma\lambda(M_n)t^n \in \mathbb{Z}[[t]]$ ($\textit{Poincare series}$)

The proof is given by following.
[image]

Everything is clear for me, except for $\textit{how we define $L_n$ for small n}$?, especially $n$ is smaller than $k_s$. I strongly guess that we have to define $L_n=M_n$.

There is some more detailed proof of this theorem in google, but I can't still find what is exactly $L_n$ for small $n$. Can anyone tell me what is $L_n$ and
if $L_n=M_n$ is true for such small $n$ as I mentioned, then can you tell me WHY L is a graded $A$-module? (Since $\textit{Poincare series}$ defined on graded $A$-module)

Comment: I guess you can define $L_n$ for $n<k_s$ either as $0$ or as $M_n$, it doesn't matter. The two possible $P(L,t)$ will differ by $\sum_{n=0}^{k_s-1} \lambda(M_n)t^n$, what doesn't change the argument. But in practice, if $L_n$ is not actually defined for $n<k_s$, then the "canonical" choice is to say it is $0$

Comment: @AlexL
AH! Thank you so much

Comment: A little late to the party but here we need to define $L_n=M_n$ for small n! The proof argues that $L$ is finitely generated as an $A$-Module because it is a quotient of $M$. Thus, we shall obtain $L$ by modding out an appropriate $A$-submodule $K$, say, of $M$. Let $K=\bigoplus K_n$ and for $n\ge k_s$ we take $K_n=\operatorname{im} ( \cdot x_s:M_{n-k_s}\to M_n)$ and for $0\le n < k_s$ we take $K_n=0$ this is indeed an $A$-submodule. If we took $K_n=M_n$ we would not have obtained an $A$-submodule.